# SQLite Window function avoid duplicates for aggregates

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I wish to group data in a table and select the most up to date (last) non null field for each column. I was hoping to use window functions to partition the data, however, the window function yields one result per row in the window.

Consider the following example, there is a table which contains the rows `personid` and `firstname` and `lastname`. Updates to persons are stored by inserting a row with the same `personid` and non `NULL` values for the updated fields.

To retrieve the current state one has to select the last non `NULL` values for each column grouped by `personid`.

Here is my attempt:

#### Data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "test" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "firstname" TEXT,
    "lastname"  TEXT,
    "personid"  INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
INSERT INTO "test" ("id","firstname","lastname","personid") VALUES (1,'Mark','Twain',1);
INSERT INTO "test" ("id","firstname","lastname","personid") VALUES (2,'Tom','hacksaw',2);
INSERT INTO "test" ("id","firstname","lastname","personid") VALUES (3,'Maximus',NULL,1);
```

#### Query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
    personid,
    FIRST_VALUE(firstname) OVER (PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY firstname IS NULL, id DESC) AS firstname,
    FIRST_VALUE(lastname) OVER (PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY lastname IS NULL, id DESC) AS lastname
FROM 
    test)
GROUP BY
    personid
```

Note that I have to filter my result by pumping it through a `GROUP BY`, this makes me feel that the window function `FIRST_VALUE` is computed multiple times and feels inefficient. Is there a way to window data and get one result per group? (Since I have different orderings to filter out the null values for each respective column I do not see an efficient way using `group by` clauses)

Comment: Be a lot simpler if you included all the columns in an update and not just the changed ones...

Comment: @Shawn: Good points, and I thik I will do that, however I am still wondering for academic reasons how I can accomplish what I wanted.